# RecyclerView.Adapter getItemViewType returning wrong value

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Following is my adapter code

```
public class FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

List<Object> objects;
FoodMenuParentListener foodMenuParentListener;
boolean isAddAllowed;

boolean isVegOnly;
static final int TYPE_FOOD = 0;
static final int TYPE_MENU_ITEM = 1;


public FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter(List<Object> objects, FoodMenuParentListener foodMenuParentListener, boolean isVegOnly, boolean isAddAllowed) {
    this.foodMenuParentListener = foodMenuParentListener;
    this.isVegOnly = isVegOnly;
    this.isAddAllowed = isAddAllowed;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object object = objects.get(position);
    if (object instanceof FoodMenuItem) {
        return TYPE_FOOD;
    } else if(this.objects.get(position) == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Null object added");
    }else {
        return TYPE_MENU_ITEM;
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view;
    switch (getItemViewType(i)) {
        case TYPE_FOOD:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_food_parent, viewGroup, false);
            return new MenuViewHolder(view);
        case TYPE_MENU_ITEM:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_food_child, viewGroup, false);
            return new ChildMenuHolder(view);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid viewType");

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Object object = objects.get(i);
    Context context = viewHolder.itemView.getContext();
    Log.d("myAdapter","position"+ i + ":"+ ((getItemViewType(i) == TYPE_MENU_ITEM) ? "TYPE_MENU_ITEM" : "TYPE_FOOD"));
     if (getItemViewType(i) == TYPE_MENU_ITEM) {
        ChildMenuHolder childMenuHolder = (ChildMenuHolder) viewHolder;
        GmrApplication gmrApplication = (GmrApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        Item item = (Item) object;
        childMenuHolder.tvPrice.setText(gmrApplication.getCurrencySymbolString() + item.getPrice());
        childMenuHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        childMenuHolder.txtQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuatity()));
        childMenuHolder.txtCartInc.setVisibility(item.isAddedToCart() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        childMenuHolder.txtQty.setVisibility(item.isAddedToCart() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        childMenuHolder.txtCartDec.setVisibility(item.isAddedToCart() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        childMenuHolder.btnAdd.setVisibility(!item.isAddedToCart() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        childMenuHolder.btnAdd.setBackgroundResource(isAddAllowed ? R.drawable.rounded_bottom_edge_shape_food : R.drawable.rounded_bottom_edge_shape_disable);
        childMenuHolder.btnAdd.setTextColor(isAddAllowed ? ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.button_green) : ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray_a1));
        childMenuHolder.ivType.setColorFilter(item.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(Item.FOOD_TYPE_VEG) ? ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_green) : ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.app_red));
    } else {
        FoodMenuItem foodMenuItem = (FoodMenuItem) object;
        MenuViewHolder menuViewHolder = (MenuViewHolder) viewHolder;
        if (isVegOnly) {
            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Item item : foodMenuItem.getItems()) {
                if (item.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(Item.FOOD_TYPE_VEG)) {
                    items.add(item);
                }
            }
            menuViewHolder.tvNumItems.setText("(" + items.size() + " items)");

        } else {
            menuViewHolder.tvNumItems.setText("(" + foodMenuItem.getItems().size() + " items)");

        }
        menuViewHolder.ivArrow.setImageResource(foodMenuItem.isExpanded() ? R.drawable.chev_up : R.drawable.chev_down);
        menuViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(foodMenuItem.getCategoryName());
    }


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvNumItems;
    ImageView ivArrow;
    // RecyclerView rvMenu;
    View rlArrow;

    public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvNumItems = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumItems);
        ivArrow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrow);
        // rvMenu.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        rlArrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlArrow);
        rlArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (foodMenuParentListener != null) {
                    Object object = objects.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    if (object instanceof FoodMenuItem) {
                        FoodMenuItem foodMenuItem = (FoodMenuItem) object;
                        foodMenuParentListener.OnExpandClick(foodMenuItem, getAdapterPosition());

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (foodMenuParentListener != null) {
                    Object object = objects.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    if (object instanceof FoodMenuItem) {
                        FoodMenuItem foodMenuItem = (FoodMenuItem) object;
                        foodMenuParentListener.OnExpandClick(foodMenuItem, getAdapterPosition());

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public boolean isVegOnly() {
    return isVegOnly;
}

public void setVegOnly(boolean vegOnly) {
    isVegOnly = vegOnly;
}

public interface FoodMenuParentListener extends AddItemListener {
    public void OnExpandClick(FoodMenuItem foodMenuItem, int position);

    public void OnVegOnlyClicked();
}

public class ChildMenuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView ivType;
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvPrice;
    TextView txtCartDec;
    TextView txtQty;
    TextView txtCartInc;

    Button btnAdd;

    public ChildMenuHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivType = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivType);
        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        txtCartDec = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCartDec);
        txtQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
        txtCartInc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCartInc);
        btnAdd = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtCartInc.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtCartDec.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}

public void setExpandIndex(int expandIndex) {
}

public boolean isItemExpanded(int position) {
    return true;
}


public class VegOnlyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Switch wtVeg;

    public VegOnlyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        wtVeg = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wtVeg);
        wtVeg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (foodMenuParentListener != null) {
                    foodMenuParentListener.OnVegOnlyClicked();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


public interface AddItemListener {
    public void onAddClicked(Item item, int parentIndex);

    public void increaseItemCount(Item item, int parentIndex);

    public void decreaseItemCount(Item item, int parentIndex);
}

public void addAll(int position, List<Item> objectsToAdd) {
    this.objects.addAll(position, objectsToAdd);
}

public void addItem(int position, Item object) {
    this.objects.add(position, object);
}
public void removeItem(Object object) {
    this.objects.remove(object);
}


public void removeAll(List<Item> objectsToRemove) {
    objects.removeAll(objectsToRemove);
    Log.d("myAdapter","item at first position after remove" + ":"+objects.get(0));
    Log.d("myAdapter","item at second position after remove" + ":"+objects.get(1));
}

public Object isItemInList(Item item) {
    for (Object object : objects) {
        if (object instanceof Item && ((Item) object).getId().equals(item.getId())) {
            return object;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Following is code in my Fragment to expand collapse RecyclerView

```
 @Override
        public void OnExpandClick(FoodMenuItem foodMenuItem, int position) {
            if (recyclerViewMenu != null && recyclerViewMenu.getAdapter() != null) {
                recyclerViewMenu.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
                FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter foodMenuRecyclerAdapter = (FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter) recyclerViewMenu.getAdapter();
                foodMenuItem.setExpanded(!foodMenuItem.isExpanded());
                if (foodMenuItem.isExpanded()) {
                    foodMenuRecyclerAdapter.addAll(position + 1, foodMenuItem.getItems());
                    foodMenuRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, foodMenuItem.getItems().size());

                } else {
                    foodMenuRecyclerAdapter.removeAll(foodMenuItem.getItems());
                    foodMenuRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position + 1, foodMenuItem.getItems().size());

                }

            }

        }
```

**Now after collapsing first item I have checked log for type of first two items in list found that first two items are of type ParentItem which is FoodMenuItem but when I checked log for getItemViewType for same positions it is returning wrong value somehow**

Following are logs

```
05-28 00:13:47.643 32010-32010/com.myapp.android D/myAdapter: item at first position after remove:com.myapp.android.pojoentities.FoodMenuItem@7fdf002
05-28 00:13:47.643 32010-32010/com.myapp.android D/myAdapter: item at second position after remove:com.myapp.android.pojoentities.FoodMenuItem@9cbfd13
05-28 00:13:47.664 32010-32010/com.myapp.android D/myAdapter: position1:TYPE_FOOD
05-28 00:13:47.678 32010-32010/com.myapp.android D/myAdapter: position2:TYPE_MENU_ITEM
```

due to this I am getting following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.android.food.menu.FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter$MenuViewHolder cannot be cast to com.myapp.android.food.menu.FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter$ChildMenuHolder
    at com.myapp.android.food.menu.FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FoodMenuRecyclerAdapter.java:76)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3875)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1183)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:889)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at com.myapp.android.custom.FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout.onLayout(FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout.java:247)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLay
```